# Get a value from a data-attribute of multiple selected dropdowns (Dynamic dropdowns)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the data attribute of the selected dropdown to an input box and the given code works perfectly for single dropdown included in the page and it outputs the data attribute to the input box.

But when i add two or more dropdowns the value doesn't come properly. I'm working with dynamic data which i retrieve from a DB so the amount of dropdowns can differ. How can i write the js code to be dynamic?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select.material-price').change(function() {
    var materialValue = $('select.material-price').find(':selected').data('price');
    $('.material-total').val(materialValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <select class="material-price">
            <option data-price="100000" value="10">Material A</option>
            <option data-price="400000" value="20>">Material B</option>
            <option  data-price="500000" value="30">Material C</option>
        </select>
    <input type="text" class="material-total" readonly />
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <select class="material-price">
            <option data-price="100000" value="10">Material A</option>
            <option data-price="400000" value="20>">Material B</option>
            <option  data-price="500000" value="30">Material C</option>
        </select>
    <input type="text" class="material-total" readonly />
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `$(this)` jquery to get the value from fired select's data and use `$next()` to assign value to input sits immediate next to select.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select.material-price').change(function() {
    var materialValue = $(this).find(':selected').data('price');
    $(this).next('.material-total').val(materialValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <select class="material-price">
        <option data-price="100000" value="10">Material A</option>
        <option data-price="400000" value="20>">Material B</option>
        <option  data-price="500000" value="30">Material C</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="material-total" readonly />
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <select class="material-price">
        <option data-price="100000" value="10">Material A</option>
        <option data-price="400000" value="20>">Material B</option>
        <option  data-price="500000" value="30">Material C</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="material-total" readonly />
  </div>
```

**Update:** when using `select2` jquery surely your structure will get change on dom. so obviously we need to restructure the query too. check below snippet for reference.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.select2').select2();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select.material-price').change(function() {
    var materialValue = $(this).select2().find(":selected").data("price");
    $(this).parent('.row').find('.material-total').val(materialValue);
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.4/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <select class="material-price select2">
      <option value="100000" value="10">Material A</option>
      <option data-price="400000" value="20>">Material B</option>
      <option data-price="500000" value="30">Material C</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="material-total" readonly />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <select class="material-price select2">
      <option data-price="100000" value="10">Material A</option>
      <option data-price="400000" value="20>">Material B</option>
      <option data-price="500000" value="30">Material C</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="material-total" readonly />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi So i have used this library (https://select2.org/) in order to get a dropdown search, when i use the specific class to activate the dropdown search, your code doesn't work. Any reason why? 

But when i remove the "select2" class it works perfectly.

Comment: not able to get it what you are talking about. can you please share a fiddler?

Comment: I'm trying use (https://select2.org/). But when i try to use it by adding the class for the "select dropdown" library. Your code stops working for some reason. 

https://jsfiddle.net/9a32dsro/